# Visualizar proyecto de angular en red local

Tags: angular, redes

He realizado una mini aplicación web de Angular la cual corre en un equipo con Win10 en el puerto `http://localhost:4200` por medio del comando

```
ng serve
```

desde una ventana de comandos.

La aplicación funciona correctamente en la pc donde esta corriendo la cual tiene la ip `192.168.1.1`, pero como hacer para que otros usuarios de mi red local puedan acceder a la aplicacion?

Probé con `http://192.168.1.1:4200`, pero no funciona.

Comment: probá con [`ng serve --host=192.168.1.1`](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Comment: Estás seguro de que el pc tiene la IP acabando en 1.1?? Eso normalmente es la puerta de enlace, no la IP

Comment: @Benito-B, si bien es usual que el valor 192.X.X.1 (o 10.X.X.1) se asigne para la puerta de enlace, no es una regla o norma. Cualquier dirección IP puede cumplir el rol de puerta de enlace, siempre que sea una dirección válida. Saludos

Comment: Ya probaste a lanzarla en `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya sé que no es obligatorio que esa IP sea la puerta de enlace, pero ante la falta de pruebas aportadas por el autor de la pregunta creo que sería correcto empezar por lo más obvio, que es que la IP a la que está accediendo no sea la correcta

Comment: Para añadir al aporte de @aloMalbarez, no sólo servir la aplicación usando dicho host es suficiente, debes asegurarte que tanto el `firewall` y/o antivirus no estén bloqueando el puerto TCP/UDP 4200, que es donde se está levantando dicho servicio. Asumiendo que todos los otros equipos se encuentren en la misma red física y lógica, deberías poder acceder de esta forma a tu aplicación sin problemas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @aloMalbarez, era exactamente lo que necesitaba y respondiendo a Mauricio, gracias por el dato extra. Todo funciona correctamente. Como puedo calificar o votar por la respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

`ng serve` por default escucha las peticiones en [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) que normalmente apunta al ["rulo local" (loopback)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) `127.0.0.1` en ipv4 y `::1` en ipv6.

Para que atienda peticiones en otra ip ( o en otro host ) podes usar la opción [`--host`](https://angular.io/cli/serve) con el nombre del host ( queda en el sistema operativo local hacer la traducción a ip ) o directamente la ip, que en tu caso sería `ng serve --host=192.168.1.1`.

También es posible usar [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) que en términos de enganchar servicios a interfaces significa "todas las interfaces disponibles" eso incluye `localhost` (127.0.0.1) y todas las ip de cada una de tus interfaces de red ( cable, wi-fi, etc. ) aunque dependiendo de la versión del cli y del proyecto seguramente haya algún tema de cors o de chequeo de hostnames, opciones que se pueden deshabilitar pero te compromete la seguridad.

Otras configuraciones mas avanzadas incluyen `--allowedHosts=` para filtrar las ip/hosts que pueden acceder y `--publicHost=` para definir la url que debe usar el navegador para acceder, independientemente de la ip/host definida con `--host` ( por ejemplo cuando configuras un proxy reverso que traduce entre dominios/subdominios visibles desde afuera y servicios en ip:puerto locales ).

Answer (score 2):

- Si tienes windows recomiendo desactivar el firewall
- Correr el comando $ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
- Desde otro dispositivo en tu navegador poner la ip del equipo donde
  levantaste el server ejemplo http://192.168.100.5:4200/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dice `@alo Malbarez` es la respuesta pero tambien existen otras herramientas de ayuda como [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)